# Return value optimization while returning by reference

Tags: c++, reference, return-value, return-value-optimization, return-by-reference

I have read a lot of articles about return value optimization. Yet I'm not sure to fully understand if this is what takes place in the following case (the addresses are actually always identical):

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class Type
{
public:
    Type(int a) { m_a = a; }
private:
    Type(const Type & other) {}
    int m_a;
};

class Base
{
public:
    Base() : instance(42) {}
    virtual Type & GetType()
    {
        printf("Base: Address of instance: %i\n", &instance);
        return instance;
    }

private:
    Type instance;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual Type & GetType()
    {
        printf("Derived\n");
        return Base::GetType();
    }
};

int main()
{
    printf("Base class\n");
    Base b;
    printf("Main: Address of instance: %i\n", &(b.GetType()));

    printf("\nDerived class\n");
    Derived d;
    printf("Main: Address of instance: %i\n", &(d.GetType()));
}
```

Does returning by reference always ensure no copy constructor is called?
Or is [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) taking place here?

Comment: Thanks for the edition. At first I talked about "cascading" as my actual use case was for "recursively" returning a reference through an inheritance hierarchy. But in the end the question is actually independent from inheritance - which is now reflected by the edited title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does returning by reference always ensure no copy constructor is called?

Yes. When you pass or return by reference (as opposed to the passing/returning by value), no copy is being constructed.

> is [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) taking place here?

Since you return by reference, RVO has nothing to do with it here. RVO is an optimization technique that consists in elimination of a redundant copy being created while *returning by value*.

RVO might take a place if you have function like this:

```
Type GetType()
{
    Type instance;
    //...
    return instance;
}
//...
Type t = GetType();
```

then with RVO the compiler would try to eliminate the redundant **copy constructor** and **destructor** calls which means that the local `instance` from the `GetType` function would be assigned into variable `t` without a copy being created.

Answer (score 4):

> **Does returning by reference always ensure no copy constructor is called?**

RVO is an optimization technique. It is not guaranteed by the standard. Most compilers will apply RVO when you **return by value**.

```
virtual Type & GetType()
        ^^^^^^
```

You are **returning by reference** here, which means no copy needs to be created so there is  no overhead of copy constructor call and hence no chance or scope of RVO.

> **the addresses are actually always identical**

The addresses are actually always identical because they are addresses of the same class member.